# Can I use a Stored Procedure to update different Columns by passing the Column Name?

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I am using Stored Procedures for the very first time (this is in Outlook 2007 VBA) and am wondering if I need a different Procedure for each Column in my RecordSet or can I pass the Column Name as a variable ? I have written the following to try and do just that but am getting the error

> Run-time error '3709':
>
> The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either
>   closed or invalid in this context.

This is my code ...

```vb
Call ConnectToDatabase

KA_Com.CommandText = "ReadLeagues"
KA_Com.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pLeagueName", Type:=adChar, Size:=Len(KAleague))

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pLeagueName").Value = UCase(KAleague)

Set KA_RS_Leagues = KA_Com.Execute

If KA_RS_Leagues![Session] > 0 Then
    MsgBox "E:Mail received with Fixture List attachment, but Session is not 0 or -1. E:Mail moved to 'Unknown' Folder"
    EMail.Move SubFolder2
    MySkip = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Atmt.SaveAsFile KApath & KAleague & "/Current Season/" & Atmt.FileName
Atmt.SaveAsFile KApath & KAleague & "/Current Season/Fixtures.txt"

SubFolder1.Items(EMailNo).Delete

Set KA_Com = New ADODB.Command

KA_Com.CommandText = "UpdateEmails"
KA_Com.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pLeagueId", Type:=adInteger)

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pLeagueId").Value = KA_RS_Leagues![ID]

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pColumnName", Type:=adChar, Size:=11)

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pColumnName").Value = "FixtureList"

Set KA_Parameter = KA_Com.CreateParameter(Name:="pColumnValue", Type:=adInteger, Size:=1)

KA_Com.Parameters.Append KA_Parameter
KA_Com.Parameters("pColumnValue").Value = 1

Set KA_RS_Leagues = KA_Com.Execute <<< This is where I hit the Error
```

My ConnectToDatabase routine ...

```vb
Sub ConnectToDatabase()

Set KA_DB = New ADODB.Connection

Set KA_RS_Leagues = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_RS_LeagueTypes = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_RS_Managers = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_RS_Teams = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_RS_Emails = New ADODB.Recordset
Set KA_RS_Scouting = New ADODB.Recordset

Set KA_Com = New ADODB.Command

KADB_String = "Server=GARYSPC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=KADB; Trusted_Connection=yes"

With KA_DB
  .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
  .ConnectionString = KADB_String
  .Open
End With

Set KA_Com.ActiveConnection = KA_DB

End Sub
```

And, of course, my Stored Procedure that fails ...

```vb
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
    @pLeagueId int,
    @pColumnName nChar,
    @pColumnValue int

AS

    UPDATE [dbo].[Emails]

    SET @pColumnName = @pColumnValue

    WHERE [League] = @pLeagueId;

    GO
```

Any help very much appreciated ...

Comment: It is worth mentioning on what line the error is raised. Step through code with F8 and note where error is highlighted. And by mention, I mean [edit] into your question.

Comment: No you can't parameterize object or column names. That would require dynamic sql. Why do you now know which column to update? That is usually a sign that the design is not properly normalized.

Comment: Do you have known list of columns that would be in the update statement? This can possibly be done without dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange 100% agreed: needing dynamic column names smells like denormalized data. *Especially* given `@pColumnValue` is an `int`. I'd be very curious to see the actual table's `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: Also you'll want to specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and declare all variables you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your replies ... This is a small table that is keeping track of incoming E:Mails that will arrive in a particular order, that is how I know the column names and these are factored by the details of the E:Mail Subject or Attachment. I can of course (and now will !) have separate code for each one, all I was trying to do was to make my code shorter and hopefully more efficient, i.e. modular.

Also, the ColumnValue being an Int is because the Columns are Binary and so I am setting them to True when each particular E:Mail has arrived.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL would be the simplest solution. Done right:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
     @leagueId int not null
    ,@columnName nvarchar(50) not null -- note capped length; adjust as needed
    ,@columnValue int not null
AS
BEGIN
    -- forgetting this tends to mess up ADODB clients, esp. with SELECT queries:
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- parameters for the dynamic SQL:
    DECLARE @sqlParams nvarchar(max) = N'
        @leagueId int not null
       ,@columnValue int not null
    ';
    -- build the dynamic SQL, notice QUOTENAME and parameter usage:
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
        UPDATE [dbo].[Emails]
          SET ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' = @columnValue
        WHERE [LeagueId] = @leagueId;
    ';
    -- run it:
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @sqlParams, @leagueId, @columnValue;
END
```

That said, needing dynamic column names smells like `[dbo].[Emails]` isn't properly normalized: the *ideal* solution probably involves going back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
@pLeagueId int,
@pColumnName nChar,
@pColumnValue int

AS
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ''


set @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE [dbo].[Emails] '

set @sql = @sql + 'SET   QUOTENAME(' + @pColumnName + ')  = ' + cast(@pColumnValue   as varchar(25)) + ' '

set @sql = @sql + '    WHERE [League] = ' +  cast(@pLeagueId  as varchar(25))

print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@pColumnValue varchar(25)',@pLeagueId varchar(25)
```

Comment: This would "work" until bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ This is wide open to sql injection. At the very least you should wrap the column name with QUOTENAME to help.

Comment: agreed with that but im not here to fix his sec issues

Comment: There wasn't one to fix until you suggested he use unsafe code. At the very least you should mention that your code is vulnerable. It seems the OP is fairly new and might take your code as good way of doing this.

Comment: The only reason I have even looked at coding this the way I have is because my original code was pointed out to be wide open to SQL Injection !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sp_execitesql to run inside your stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmails]
@pLeagueId int,
@pColumnName nChar,
@pColumnValue int

AS
DECLARE @Sql as nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = N'UPDATE [dbo].[Emails] SET ' + QUOTENAME(@pColumnName) + ' = CAST(@pColumnValue AS varchar(20) WHERE [League] = CAST(@pLeagueId AS varchar(20);'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, @pColumnValue, @pLeagueId
GO
```

Comment: i believe this will error as pColmnValue is an int and you cannot add that to a string

Comment: This is wide open to sql injection too.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't accept any of the above answers as I didn't go down that road and make things over-complicated, I just created a different Stored Procedure & VBA routind for each variable.

Thanks for your helpful replies though, hopefully they will help somebody else in the future ...